# How do I publish to Service Fabric using Windows Authentication?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My cluster is using Windows Authentication for client to endpoint and it works as expected in browser when connecting to cluster by prompting to use username/password to connect to SF console.
I'm confused as far as what I'm supposed to put into publish profile in Visual Studio. There is no option to choose Windows Authentication anywhere, only cert and Azure Active Directory. How is it supposed to work?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using WindowsCredential="True" in the publish profile should work.  Here is a powershell version that has worked for me in the past.

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint:':19000' -WindowsCredential:$true -TimeoutSec:60

Comment: For anybody having this issue following parameter needs to be added to publish profile `<ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="containerhost1"  WindowsCredential="true"/>`